# About Executing non-query

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to use following query but it doesn't give expected result.
Following is my query:

```
string Rapdate = Convert.ToString(db.ExecuteNonQuery("select top(1) convert(varchar(50),PrcT_Date,106) from PriceMasterTemp",CommandType.Text));
```

It returns me -1 instead of returning date.
What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use **EXecuteReader**() instead Of ExecuteNonQuery

Because **ExecuteNonQuery** is used for Insert , Update and Delete queries

**EXecuteReader** is used to retrieve the values from table

Ex:

```
String sql = "select top(1) convert(varchar(50),PrcT_Date,106) from PriceMasterTemp";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,conn);
ResultLabel.Text = (String) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN about [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the **number of rows affected**
```

This method returnd just numbers of rows affected, if you want get value of date and there is just one value you can use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top(1) convert(varchar(50),PrcT_Date,106) from PriceMasterTemp",connetcion)
string date = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```